# Can't update react state, even component is not unmounted

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware

## Description

I have component which shows data that get from server and display it on the table using the state, tableData and **it must be set** when Redux action is dispatched.

I've use action listener library which uses `Redux middleware` which consisting of 63 lines of code. [redux-listeners-qkreltms](https://github.com/qkreltms/redux-listeners).

For example when I register a function on `analysisListIsReady({}).type` which is `ANALYSISLIST_IS_READY` then when the action is dispatched, the function is called.

## Issue

The issue is that react throws sometimes the error: `Can't update react state...` for `setTableData` so response data is ignored to be set. I want to figure it out when it happens.

I've assumed that it's because of unmounting of component, so I printed some logs, but none of logs are printed and also ComponentA is not disappeared.

It's not throing any error when I delete `getAnalysisJsonPathApi` and `getResource`, so I tried to reporuduce it, but failed... [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-listener-with-next-g7fgt?file=/components/Test1.js)

It's not throing any error when I delete `listenMiddleware.addListener` see: #2

#1

```
// ComponentA
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log("unmounted1")
}}, [])  

useEffect(() => {
    listenMiddleware.addListener(analysisListIsReady({}).type, (_) => {
      try {
        getAnalysisJsonPathApi().then((res) => {
          //...
          getResource(volumeUrl)
            .then((data: any) => {
              // ...
              setTableData(data)
            })
        })
      } catch (error) {
        warn(error.message)
      }
    })

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted2")
    }
  }, [])
```

```
export const getAnalysisJsonPathApi = () => {
  return api
    .post('/segment/volume')
    .then(({ data }) => data)

export const getResource = async (src: string, isImage?: boolean): Promise<ArrayBuffer> =>
  api
    .get(src)
    .then(({ data }) => data)
```

#2

```
// ComponentA
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log("unmounted1")
}}, [])  

useEffect(() => {
    if (steps.step2a) {
      try {
        getAnalysisJsonPathApi().then((res) => {
          //...
          getResource(volumeUrl)
            .then((data: any) => {
              // ...
              setTableData(data)
            })
        })
      } catch (error) {
        warn(error.message)
      }
    }

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted2")
    }
  }, [steps.step2a])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out it's because of redux-listeners-qkreltms, Redux middleware.

It keeps function when component is mounted into listener, but never changes its functions even component is unmounted.

```js
  middleware.addListener = (type, listener) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < listeners.length; i += 1) {
      if (listeners[i].type === type) {
        return;
      }
    }
    listeners.push(createListener(type, listener));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, its as you said:

> because of unmounting of component

In your `UseEffect()` function, you need to check if the componenet is mounted or not, in other words, you need to do the `componentDidMount` &  `componentDidUpdate` (if needed) logics:

```
const mounted = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
if (!mounted.current) {
    // do componentDidMount logic
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    mounted.current = true;
} else {
    // do componentDidUpdate logic
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i didn't go to your question code detail, but my hint might help you, usually this error happens in fetchData function,
suppose you have a fetchData function like below:

```
fetchData(){
...
let call = await service.getData();
...
--->setState(newItems)//Here
}
```

so when api call end and state want to be updated, if component been unmounted, there is no state to be set,
you can use a bool variable and set it false when component will unmount:

```
    let stillActive= true;
    
    fetchData(){
    active = true;
    ...
    let call = await service.getData();
    ...
    if(stillActive)
       setState(newItems)//Here
    }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        active = false;
    }
```